# Can tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer take an arbitrary input with an arbitrary function?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a lot of code which will make it hard to post. I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ["<tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=(1, 191440, 4, 4, 4, 3) dtype=float32_ref>"] and loss Tensor("softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_sg/Reshape_2:0", shape=(1,), dtype=float32).
```

So, I am wondering whether I am using tf.train incorrectly. Given an arbitrary input X, arbitrary differentiable functions f and g, and output Y and a graph where Y = g(f(X)), can I just use tf.train like this:

```
optim_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(
    learning_rate).minimize(loss(of Y), var_list=[X])
```

Where the dimensions of X and Y differ.